# Preventing a resizable parent widget from being resized by child widgets

Tags: qt4

Is it possible to create a widget in Qt4 whose size can be changed interactively (e.g. by clicking and dragging the edge), but whose size will not change when its children widgets are added, removed, or resized?

In other words, as I populate the widget with children, the children shrink as necessary to maintain the parent geometry. However, if the parent is expanded, the children expand to fill the new space.